# The system cannot find the path specified1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-jobs

win i run this cod i have this error

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Mettco1>  * * * * * php /c/Users/Administrator/Mettco1/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: working on windows or linux?

Comment: windows i think solved it in Task schedule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for setting up your schedule, so you need to add this your server crontab 
type `crontab -e` from your server terminal and paste that code there, for setting up the cron.

But if you want to test on the local server just run the artisan command that you have added to the `scheduler`